# How to return a string which matches the regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

Here is a method which returns true/ false for each match. Instead I want to get the matched string if it matches. If it doesn't matches then don't return.
I can have an If condition to check if its true or false. But my specific question here is, how to return the string if it matches?

```
private static boolean IsMatch(String s, String pattern) {
        try {
            Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(s);
            return matcher.matches();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return false;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Return `null` if there is no match. Return the `String` value if there is.

Comment: so you want to return `true/ false/ String` How? return `String` either `null` or matched one.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis return matcher; doesn't work, what to use?

Comment: @user3882418 Check out the `Matcher` methods. There's one to return the match.

Comment: @user3218114 true and false stuff I can do, but my question is how to get the **string**.

Comment: Change the method return-type from `boolean` to `String`. Then you'll be able to return a `String` instead of a boolean. Basic stuff

Comment: @VinceEmigh hello! I can change that, but the value which I'm returning should also be string. That's what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to get the matched string?

Change the method return to `String` and return the the desired matched group if found.

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    return matcher.group(); // you can get it from desired index as well
} else {
    return null;
}
```

---

#### Update

Use [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to get the value if matched. Check for [Optional.isPresent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--) before calling [Optional.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) to get the value.

Comment: matcher.group() is not returning string. I see the error "This method must return a result of type String" when I try to use if(matcher.find()){return matcher.group();}

Comment: minus one for not working as per last comment

Comment: @geotheory I hope the updated answer will help others.